# How to copy list items certain amount of times?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a big list of around 2000 numbers in the list. This is just an example of what I want.

I have `list1=[1,2,3,4]` and `list2=[1,3,2,5]`. I want it so that `list1[i]` will be used `list2[i]` times in the new list.

So for this example the new list would be:`list3=[1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4]`

The new `list3` has 1x1, 3x2, 2x3, 5x4.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't pretty and isn't particularly easy to understand, but works:

```
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list2 = [1, 3, 2, 5]
>>> import itertools
>>> list3 = list(itertools.chain(*[[list1[i]] * count for i, count in enumerate(list2)]))
>>> list3
[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Brief explanation...

You can multiply a list:

```
>>> [1] * 3
[1, 1, 1]
```

Using this in the list comprehension will get you a list-of-lists:

```
>>> [[list1[i]] * count for i, count in enumerate(list2)]
[[1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]]
```

You can then use itertools to flatten the list as above.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1=[1,2,3,4] 
list2=[1,3,2,5]

list3 = []
for a, b in zip(list1, list2):
    for i in range(b):
        list3.append(a)

list3 == [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

```
list1=[1,2,3,4] 
list2=[1,3,2,5]

z=[]
for x,y in zip(list1,list2):
  z.extend([x] * y)

print z
```